# Google Places API for Android

Tags: android, google-places-api

Всем добра! Ребята, нужна ваша помощь.

Как правильно сгенерировать `BROWSER_API_KEY_FOR_PLACES` для `Google Places API for Android`?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Что нужно выбрать? для `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?`, `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?`

**Update:** Разобрался.

Comment: Было бы хорошо, если б вы ответ в ответ написали - так вопрос движком сайта будет означен как "отвеченный" =)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб оке, сейчас исправлю ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Практически во всех туториалах пишут следующее:

*We can create API key for Google Place API by clicking “Create new Browser key”  available at the “API Access” pane of the Google console. Also ensure that, “Places API” is enabled in the “Services” pane of the Google console.*

Коварная строка **Create new Browser key**, которая заставила меня помучиться.

Так вот "Что нужно выбрать? для https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?, https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?"

**Во-первых нам пригодится следующее из подключенных API:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тут же мы можем увидеть запросы, которые прошли или не прошли (как доказательство тому, что ключ используется нужный):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И еще, чтобы проверить правильный ли ключ используется, пробейте запрос в браузере: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=32.1145134,34.8269532&radius=5000&types=parknig&sensor=true&key=AIzaSyDqqAdbsJwVT8LbjY0sGFXeiJBwCiUFV70

*Только ключ поменяйте на свой)*

**Во-вторых создавать нужно !Ключ для сервера!, а не для браузера:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Туториал](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/showing-nearby-places-using-google-places-api-and-google-map-android-api-v2/), который я использовал староват, но рабочий (в плане кода - инфа 100), а из библиотек достаточно таки будет подключить `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:...'`.

P.S. Надеюсь ответ кому-нить пригодится:)