# Отображение на карте конкретных обьектов в android приложении

Tags: java, android

Есть задача сделать activity с google maps, на которой отображается кокретный тип обьектов размещенных поблизости  (пр. только магазины). Нужен совет, как реализовать подобно, возможно пример кода. Все, что может помочь

Answer (score 2):

Сначала начните с [официальной документации со всеми возможными кодами](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/start).

---

Потом, как получите карту, используйте [Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchRequests).

*И проделайте следующее:*

- Получить отдельный ключ для `Places API`.
- Реализовать запрос.

> Например (Google рекомендует использовать JSON):
>
> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location= 
>   местоположение_пользователя(координаты)&radius=необходимый_радиус&types=[необходимый_тип
>   смотрите_тут](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/supported_types)&sensor=true&key=ваш_ключ

- Распарсить необходимые данные, включая координаты магазинов, чтобы отобразить маркеры на карте.

---

Возможно ещё поможет [следующее](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/534342/google-places-api-for-android). А также пример [кода](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/showing-nearby-places-using-google-places-api-and-google-map-android-api-v2/).